# how to Post Data to a Database through an api for Dynamically Add or Remove Table Rows in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular7

i am creating a form with dynamically add and delete row functionality .
but i don't know how to post data to the api

tried using the http client couldnt get through with it

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mr22to?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

here is my code

solution to post data to backend through api

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You forgot to add your code.

Comment: Sorry, if you could help me with how to post data for nested forms, since the code uses that concept. Thanks in advance : )